# Seek for advice. Fizz buzz coding challenge (conditional statements)

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to JS and I am working on a FizzBuzz challenge. Below is what I have tried Essentially when the function takes a value then it would iterate from 1 up to the value and an array would result.

I am hoping  to seek advice on adding conditional checking such as: 1) if the value n is less than 4, it will return the string: "Please insert a value greater than or equal to 4" and 2) if the function is passed no value, it should return an empty array. I am not sure where to add and should I be using if...else or simply if for each conditional checking. Much obliged.

```
var fizzBuzz = function(n, arr = []) {   
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  if (n === 1) {                         
    arr.push('1');
    return arr.reverse();
  } else {                               
    if (n % 4 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
      arr.push('FIZZBUZZ');
    } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
      arr.push('Buzz');
    } else if (n % 4 === 0) {
      arr.push('Fizz');
    } else {
      arr.push('' + n);
    }
    return fizzBuzz(n - 1, arr);         
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your code working? If it is, then you should post to codereview.stackexchange for advice on improving it. If it is not working, do add the expected and actual output

Comment: One piece of advice. Always return the same type. Don't return a string sometimes and an array others. This makes it tricky for the caller to deal with,

Comment: Perhaps an alternative to returning a string is to throw an exception?

Comment: Thanks Paul, however it seems that I would have to use 'try' , 'catch' which I am not supposed to use at this stage of the course since they have not been covered.

Answer (score 0):

## You may be overthinking this

1. The number one job of code is to make sense to programmers.
2. Deeply-nested conditionals are hard to make sense of and hard to maintain. So: keep all conditional paths as short as possible, and never put the happy-path inside an `if`.

Here are your requirements:

> 1. if the value n is less than 4, it will return the string: "Please insert a value greater than or equal to 4"
> 2. if the function is passed no value, it should return an empty array

Rule #1 suggests we'll express the conditions exactly as you described them.

Rule #2 suggests that we'll handle those special cases first, in short, terminal branches, with the remainder of the function handling the default scenario. This will keep the function nice and flat (i.e. few levels of indentation, which helps control [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)), and make it easier for future devs to skim the implementation.

```js
function fizzBuzz( n ) {
  // if the function is passed no value, it should return an empty array
  // I put this case first to avoid having to figure out whether `undefined < 4`
  if( n === undefined ) {
    // this is a short, terminal branch
    return []
  }
  
  // if the value n is less than 4, it will return a specific string
  if( n < 4 ) {
    // this is a short, terminal branch
    return 'Please insert a value greater than or equal to 4'
  }
  
  // this is the trunk: it will be as long as the happy path requires
  let out = []
  for( let i = 1; i < n; i++ ) out.push(i)
  
  return out
}
```

---

If you're new to JS and looking for some general tips, you could do worse than [my own Javascript guidelines](https://gist.github.com/tomprogers/a5594cdb8fbe59e040dbcd89308d639b).